# Limit Rotation in Custom Space

Tags: armature

I'm trying to rig a shoulder in Blender, and apply realistic joint limits (from range of motion studies) to the rig. However, there's the problem that range of motion itself depends on the current position of the of the joint.

This is most obvious if you try to rig the shoulder in local space. If you hold your arm out to the side and then lift it over your head, you can have a different range of motion than if you hold your arm out in front of you and lift it from there. But, in local space, the first is an X-axis rotation, and the second is *still* an X-axis rotation but with a Z-axis rotation first, to move the arm out in front.

Now, in pose space, this problem goes away, since your rotation axes no longer change based on previous rotations: one of these will be X and the other will be Y and you're done. But in pose space I run into the problem where Blender can't handle limits that cross -180 degrees. I *thought* that I could similarly bypass that problem by using a custom space anchored on the clavicle bone; since it doesn't rotate when I rotate the upper arm, its X and Y axes shouldn't change and I should be able to set rotation limits based on its fixed reference frame.

But since the clavicle bone is in fact the parent of the upper-arm bone, that space is local space anyway! Which means I probably misunderstood what exactly is going wrong in the above, somewhere.

Help?